# Ошибка ссылки. Что писать перед .setBackgroundResource

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Что нужно написать перед .setBackgroundResource? Ссылку на Layout? Написал id лэйаута но все равно не получается

//цель кода измениние `background` лейаута

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private View.OnClickListener redButtonListener;
        private ImageSwitcher mImageSwitcher;
        int position = 0;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") final Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.ontheleft);
            s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (s.isChecked()) {
                        ???.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.donkey2);
                    } else {
                        ???.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fiona);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Left"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Right" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: перед использованием ссылки на лэйаут, его нужно "найти" на разметке методом `LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout1);`. к полученному из этого метода View можно применять уже методы, как `layout.setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: Добавил,ссылку на лейаут, приложение вылетает, вот Logcat                                                                                                          `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.t1/com.example.t1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Насколько я знаю фон изменить невозможно. Назначить его можно только единожды, но попробуй добавить getResources() перед getBackgraund... Если не поможет, то изменить фон получится только с помощью селектора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сначала инициализировать нужный элемент, например:

```
final Button buttonName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
buttonName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fiona);
```